# Checkmarx : How to solve Unsafe_Use_Of_Target_blank issue?

Tags: javascript, security, code-analysis, checkmarx

I have 3 occurances of *"Unsafe_Use_Of_Target_blank"* vulnerability from *Checkmarx*, in the following lines of my code (UI5 project):

```js
window.open(new URL(sCustomUrl).origin + "/" + sParam);

window.open(sCustomUrl + this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/ID"));

window.open(this.urlToID);
```

How can I eliminate the issue in these lines?

Comment: Please paste the error description from *Checkmarx* here

Comment: @baruchiro In checkmarx at these lines, it is shown that the vulnerability is existing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When not specifying the target (no second parameter for `window.open`, or it an **empty string** or `"_blank"`), the opened window gains some access to the page that executed the `window.open()` method ([Reverse Tabnabbing](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Reverse_Tabnabbing)).

Setting the opener property to `null`, or specifically setting the target when calling `window.open`, fixes this vulnerability.

You can get more info about "unsafe use of target _blank" [here](https://hackernoon.com/unsafe-use-of-target_blank-39413ycf).

Comment: @S Shahar
I have given the attribute "noopener, noreferrer" . 

window.open(sCustomUrl + this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/ID"), "_blank", "noopener, noreferrer");

But the issue is still existing. eventhough after passing the attribute-  "noopener, noreferrer". 
What would be the reason? How can I resolve this.?